# Why am I running out of space?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, motorola-moto-g2

My phone (a Moto G 2nd Gen running Android 5.0.2) says I currently have 441MB of free space on my phone. I am trying to download an app that is 27MB. My phone refuses to let me, because it says I don't have enough space. I've moved everything I possibly can to the SD card (apps, pictures, etc) and have deleted my cached files.

There's obviously enough space for this app to be downloaded. Why does my phone think that it's not got enough space?

Comment: What is the size of data partition? Use [DiskInfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.kuder.diskinfo) to find that easily.

Comment: @Firelord DiskInfo says it is 5.5 GB with 551 MB free.

Comment: After moving to SD card, Try to restart your phone and then check it out